# Back to basics: How do I get/analyze stats on a Azure website?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm struggling with a simpliest question with my websites on Azure. 
How to get/analyze stats about common stuff such as Robots/Spider visits, Referring sites, Browsers,  etc --- all the basics back to 90's.. 
Okay, I can set Web Server logging On. Then, what next? Should I upload the log files into a third party tool or something? 
Thanks for an advise.
Armin

Answer (score 3):

Integrate with **Azure Application Insights**, **New Relic** or **Google Analytics**.

Here's a screenshot from Application Insights:

[image: AppInsights]